# Spinner is cutting off dropdown list when showing keyboard

Tags: android

I have a Spinner as:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
```

It's inside a activity displayed as a dialog (I don't know if it matters, but...) `<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog" ... />`

It works fine, showing all the five itens.

[image]

Until the keyboard I open the keyboard. Now, the first item is cut and cannot be scrolled to it.

[image]

I tried to put a listener for click in this spinner and close the keyboard, but I got an error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead`

What is the fix for this behavior?

Comment: You probably want a basic on touch listener in the spinner and then remove the keyboard when a touch event is received.

Comment: @TyFlyGuy It works too, but I got others problems using this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to change the soft input mode for the activity in your manifest file. Something like this:

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" ... >
```